# Get Renamed File Names of JavaScript Forms in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, upload, filenames

I have a multiple image upload form, and the following code is working well for uploading. I need to save file names to database to the database, but I cannot figure out how to do that properly.

**`uploadform.php`**:

```
 echo form_open_multipart('gallery/upload');
  <input type="file" name="photo" size="50" />
  <input type="file" name="thumb" size="50" />  
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>
```

**`gallery_model.php`**

```
 function multiple_upload($upload_dir = 'uploads/', $config = array())
 {

  /* Upload */  

     $CI =& get_instance();
     $files = array();

     if(empty($config))
     {
         $config['upload_path']   = realpath($upload_dir);
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png';
         $config['max_size']      = '2048';
     }

        $CI->load->library('upload', $config);

        $errors = FALSE;

        foreach($_FILES as $key => $value)
        {            
            if( ! empty($value['name']))
            {
                if( ! $CI->upload->do_upload($key))
                {                                           
                    $data['upload_message'] = $CI->upload->display_errors(ERR_OPEN, ERR_CLOSE); // ERR_OPEN and ERR_CLOSE are error delimiters defined in a config file
                    $CI->load->vars($data);

                    $errors = TRUE;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Build a file array from all uploaded files
                    $files[] = $CI->upload->data();
                }
            }
        }


        // There was errors, we have to delete the uploaded files
        if($errors)
        {                    
            foreach($files as $key => $file)
            {
                @unlink($file['full_path']);    
            }                    
        }
        elseif(empty($files) AND empty($data['upload_message']))
        {
            $CI->lang->load('upload');
            $data['upload_message'] = ERR_OPEN.$CI->lang->line('upload_no_file_selected').ERR_CLOSE;
            $CI->load->vars($data);
        }
        else
        {
            return $files;


        }



        /* -------------------------------
        Insert to database */

        // problem is here, i need file names to add db. 
        // if there is already same names file at the folder, it rename file itself. so in such case, I need renamed file name :/



    }    
}
```

Comment: hmm, just found out sth: $files[0][“file_name”]
$files[1][“file_name”] gives the renamed file names.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your model for database operations only. All the upload processing and file moving has to be done in the controller. The model has to insert the record about the photo in the database and that's about it.

And as a response to your question do a `print_r($files)` and see what it contains. It should have the original filenames. It'll probably be something like artmania said above: `$files[0]['file_name']`. You should be able to loop through your $files array with a foreach construct like this:

```
foreach($files as $file) {
  $file_name = $file['file_name'];
}
```

You can get all the other data about the file in the same way. The CodeIgniter manual says about `$this->upload->data()`:

> This is a helper function that returns
>   an array containing all of the data
>   related to the file you uploaded. Here
>   is the array prototype:

```
Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

Fore more info [check out the manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).